# Can't load javaagent

Tags: java, ubuntu

On *Ubuntu 14.04 x64*, getting this error

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Error occurred during initialization of VM agent library failed to init: instrument
```

Therefore, I can't load any java app. Tried to reinstall *java*, still doesn't work.

Could it be corrupted *jar* from ppa repo?

How to fix this?

Comment: A java agent needs to packaged with extra meta information in its jar file. Appears to be missing.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I get it but why it came like this from official repo? Maybe, I can get it elsewhere and replace current?

Comment: No idea.  Would you happen it have a JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable defined?

Comment: Try to open that file using `file-roller /usr/share/jayatanaag.jar`. If it is corrupted you should see some error. Also for what I can tell Jayatana comes from a PPA so it is not from an official repo (so it may be a packaging error).

Answer (score 1):

You already installed "jayatana" which allows to hide java application menus in Unity:
If you remove that software, that message will be gone!

```
sudo apt-get remove jayatana
```

You may also need to delete:

```
/usr/share/upstart/sessions/jayatana.conf
```

and reboot.

Comment: Is there a way to keep Jayatana *and* remove the messages?

Answer (score 1):

try to run your application, adding "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS= " in front of the command, like that:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS= java -jar jarfilename.jar
```